# How to set ckeditor text with javascript

Tags: ckeditor, javascript

Is it possible to set ckeditor text with javascript for a custom field?

I want to do something similar to the mail templates selection.

I try $('#custom_162_126').val('blub') but this only change the original field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CKEditor method [`setData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-setData):

```
CKEDITOR.instances['custom_162_126'].setData('blub');
```